# Set Camera focus on particular marker on google map on listview item click

Tags: android, json, listview, onclick, google-maps-markers

- What i want :

  - I want to set focus on marker that is already placed in google map.
  - When i click on list view item , focus of camera should be transfer to that poistion marker on map

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment)     getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

//Pass the latitude and Longitude to method

setMap(Dlat, Dlng);

```
private void setMap(double dlat, double dlng) {

    LatLng location = new LatLng(dlat, dlng);
    CameraPosition INIT = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(location).zoom(15.5F).bearing(300F) // orientation
            .tilt(50F) // viewing angle
            .build();

    // use map to move camera into position
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(INIT));

    // create initial marker
    markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(location);
    map.addMarker(markerOptions);

}
```

Comment: instead of Dlat and Dlng plz pass you latitude and  longitude

Comment: i passed my lat lon.. but no focusing on particular  marker

Comment: what u have passed vill u plz share it?

Comment: check my edited question. i posted code.. can u suggest me where should i start on listview item on click listener

Comment: why you used for loop? once you set the adapter

Comment: bcoz i want to drop multiple marker on map. so in for loop i am collecting all lat-lon and then drop on map

Comment: k. the just call the method setMap  from item click listner of Listview and pass your lat and lng .

Comment: doing same.. but camera is not focusing on particular marker

Comment: plz put hard coded lat and lng and check whether its working or not

Comment: above is full code from which i am droping marker and  getting lat-lon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106341/discussion-between-tiger-and-pradeep-gupta).